# Arraylist showing this value PlanetData@adf4bee instead of added value

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm not exactly sure if my topic is asking the right question but the situtation is this. I working on an app that is performing multiple calculations in separate classes. The calculations are being done correctly and I am able to see that they are in logcat. Now I want to display them in recyclerview and to do that I am trying to add them to an arraylist before doing a recyclerview. My arraylist is getting the values displayed in the title and its not showing in my recyclerview. Here is are my codes but based on the research I looked up I cant see what I am doing wrong.

**ArrayList Code:**

```
public class PlanetData {
private String planetRA;

private PlanetData(String planetRA){
    this.planetRA = planetRA;
}

public String getPlanetRA(){
    return planetRA;
}

public void setPlanetRA (String planetRA){
    this.planetRA = planetRA;
}

public static void main(String [] args){
        List<PlanetData> planetvalues = new ArrayList<>();

        planetvalues.add(new PlanetData("12"));
        planetvalues.add(new PlanetData(Double.toString(Mercury.getMercuryRA())));
        planetvalues.add(new PlanetData(Double.toString(Venus.getVenusRA())));
        planetvalues.add(new PlanetData(Double.toString(Moon.getMoonRA())));
        planetvalues.add(new PlanetData (Double.toString(Mars.getMarsRA())));
        planetvalues.add(new PlanetData(Double.toString(Jupiter.getJupiterRA())));
        planetvalues.add(new PlanetData(Double.toString(Saturn.getSaturnRA())));
        planetvalues.add(new PlanetData(Double.toString(Uranus.getUranusRA())));
        planetvalues.add(new PlanetData(Double.toString(Neptune.getNeptuneRA())));
        planetvalues.add(new PlanetData(Double.toString(Pluto.getPlutoRA())));

            System.out.println("This is the arraylist" + planetvalues);

}




        }
```

**RecyclerView Adapter**

```java
      public class PlanetRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlanetRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<PlanetData> mPlanetDataList;
    Context mContext;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView currentRA;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            currentRA = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.planet_location);


        }

    }

    public PlanetRecyclerViewAdapter(List<PlanetData> mPlanetDataList, Context mContext){
        this.mPlanetDataList = mPlanetDataList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public PlanetRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.planet_recycler_item,parent, false);



        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( PlanetRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.currentRA.setText(mPlanetDataList.get(position).getPlanetRA());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPlanetDataList.size();
    }
   }
```

**Fragment Activity**

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private TextView planetLongitude;
private TextView planetLatitude;
private TextView planetTime;
private TextView SunRA;
private TextView SunDEC;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
PlanetRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
List<PlanetData> items = new ArrayList<>();

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

Mercury test;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public TestFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment TestFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static TestFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);



    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);


    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.planet_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(),DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

    adapter = new PlanetRecyclerViewAdapter(items, mRecyclerView.getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);




        return view;
    }
```

> In my logcat I'm getting the following response in my arraylist: 
>   11-10 22:02:52.581 13826-13826/com.ksburneytwo.planetmathtest I/System.out: This is the arraylist[com.ksburneytwo.planetmathtest.PlanetData@adf4bee, com.ksburneytwo.planetmathtest.PlanetData@24a088f, com.ksburneytwo.planetmathtest.PlanetData@5bb671c, com.ksburneytwo.planetmathtest.PlanetData@5dd9f25, com.ksburneytwo.planetmathtest.PlanetData@17838fa, com.ksburneytwo.planetmathtest.PlanetData@ce89eab, com.ksburneytwo.planetmathtest.PlanetData@2a5d908, com.ksburneytwo.planetmathtest.PlanetData@cee08a1, com.ksburneytwo.planetmathtest.PlanetData@580eac6, com.ksburneytwo.planetmathtest.PlanetData@a907a87]

The values should be my the results of my calculations.

Comment: you have to override toString() method in PlanetData class in-order to see those values.

Comment: You should override `toString()` method for your array list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `toString()` method would result in `packagename.ClassName@hashcode`.

In your `PlanetData` class, you need to override `toString()` method, so that it can return the appropriate fields and their values.

You can generate `toString()` method using your IDE and choose what fields you want to include in the output.